# How is NSObject.setValue(value: AnyObject?, forKey key: String) implemented?

Tags: swift, nsobject

I'm asking because I want to implement that function separately into a class. I could of course just inherit from NSObject, but since it's really only one method I want I would hate getting all that other junk into my objects.

Comment: It's generally a good idea to subclass from `NSObject` when creating new objects because all that other "junk" could be really useful.

Comment: That really depends on one's purposes and for my purposes I want to create a certain class that has the bare minimum of methods so that other people can subclass them and do all what they want to do with them.

Answer (score 0):

From Command+Clicking the method:

> Given a value and a key that identifies an attribute, set the value of the attribute. Given an object and a key that identifies a to-one relationship, relate the object to the receiver, unrelating the previously related object if there was one. Given a collection object and a key that identifies a to-many relationship, relate the objects contained in the collection to the receiver, unrelating previously related objects if there were any.
>
> The default implementation of this method does the following:
>
> 1. Searches the class of the receiver for an accessor method whose name matches the pattern -set:. If such a method is found
>      the type of its parameter is checked. If the parameter type is not an
>      object pointer type but the value is nil -setNilValueForKey: is
>      invoked. The default implementation of -setNilValueForKey: raises an
>      NSInvalidArgumentException, but you can override it in your
>      application. Otherwise, if the type of the method's parameter is an
>      object pointer type the method is simply invoked with the value as the
>      argument. If the type of the method's parameter is some other type the
>      inverse of the NSNumber/NSValue conversion done by -valueForKey: is
>      performed before the method is invoked.
> 2. Otherwise (no accessor method is found), if the receiver's class' +accessInstanceVariablesDirectly method returns YES, searches
>      the class of the receiver for an instance variable whose name matches
>      the pattern _, _is, , or is, in that order. If
>      such an instance variable is found and its type is an object pointer
>      type the value is retained and the result is set in the instance
>      variable, after the instance variable's old value is first released.
>      If the instance variable's type is some other type its value is set
>      after the same sort of conversion from NSNumber or NSValue as in step
>      1.
>
>    3. Otherwise (no accessor method or instance variable is found), invokes -setValue:forUndefinedKey:. The default implementation
>         of -setValue:forUndefinedKey: raises an NSUndefinedKeyException, but
>         you can override it in your application.

Comment: That's all well and good, but I have no clue how to do all that in swift. Are those things even possible? I thought you couldn't even reflect an object's methods in swift...

Comment: I'm sure they're all possible with a little research.

Comment: Actually, you can't do any of this in Pure Swift. If you have the ObjC runtime with you, then yeah, it's the same exact code.